# GAE put object, redirect, then query for object returns null?

Tags: google-app-engine, cookies, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, webapp2

All,

I am in the process of learning Google App Engine / Webapp2 and i'm having trouble saving an object to the datastore, redirecting to another page/handler, then fetching that object from the datastore.  Forgive me if there is an easy answer to this question.  The following is a description of the code I have.

I have a base handler:

```
    class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def set_secure_cookie(self, name, val):
        cookie_val = make_secure_val(val)
        self.response.headers.add_header(
            'Set-Cookie', 
            '%s=%s; Path=/' % (name, cookie_val))

    def get_secure_cookie(self, name):
        cookie_val = self.request.cookies.get(name)
        return cookie_val and check_secure_val(cookie_val)

    def login(self, user):
        self.set_secure_cookie('user', str(user.name))

    # Called before every request and stores user object
    def initialize(self, *a, **kw):
        webapp2.RequestHandler.initialize(self, *a, **kw)
        username = self.get_secure_cookie('user')
        self.user = username and User.by_name(str(username))
```

I have a Signup page which inherits from BaseHandler:

```
class Signup(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        # Get the page

    def post(self):
        has_error = False

    # Extract and validate the input

        if has_error:
            #Re-render the form

        else:
            new_user = User.register(self.username, self.password, self.email)

            new_user.put()
            self.login(new_user)

            self.redirect("/blog/welcome")
```

If the user is a new user, the User db.Model object is created, the user is stored to the datastore, a user cookie is set and we are redirected to the Welcome handler:

```
class Welcome(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        if self.user:
            self.render('welcome.html', username = self.user.name)
        else:
            self.redirect('/blog/signup')
```

The intent here is that upon redirect, BaseHandler.initialize() would get called and would set self.user of the new user I just created.

Here is what I know: 
- When signing up a new user, I am redirected back to the signup page.
- If I then manually navigate to /blog/welcome, the page loads correctly with the new username populated.

If I add the following logging statements into Welcome.get():

```
username = self.get_secure_cookie('user')
logging.info("Cookie %r obtained inside of Welcome.get().", username)
logging.info("Found user %r", User.by_name(str(username)))
```

The cookie is obtained for the new username but no User object is found.  Again, if I navigate directly to /blog/welcome, the logs report that the cookie is obtained and the User object is found for the new user.

The User object looks like so:

```
def users_key(group = 'default'):
    return db.Key.from_path('users', group)

class User(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    password = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    email = db.StringProperty()

    @classmethod
    def by_name(cls, name):
        u = User.all().filter('name =', name).get()
        return u

    @classmethod
    def register(cls, name, password, email = None):
    return User(parent = users_key(),
                name = name,
                password = password,
                email = email)
```

Is there something about the datastore that is causing this first query to get the new user to return nothing?  How should I proceed in debugging this?  Is there additional reading I should do?  (I have tried to provide all necessary code snippets but I can provide additional code if required.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just guessing, but I suspect self.username, self.password and self.email in your RequestHandler are not set to anything.  I'm assuming you're getting those paramters from the request POST data, but that's not happening in the code shown.

The other potential problem is that your query is eventually consistent, and may not reflect recent changes (ie new User entity).  It would be much better if you fetch the user by it's key or id with a get() call instead of a query via filter().

Comment: I am extracting the parameters, I just tried to exclude as much code as possible since this was already a lengthy post.  I made a minor update to clarify.

Comment: I will try out different ways to fetch the object from the data-store this evening.  I was suspecting it might have something to do with the way in which cloud datastores operate...

Comment: Thanks @dragonx.  If I store the user id in a cookie and then use the by_id search (not shown) then this problem goes away.

Comment: great, it sounds like it was the eventually consistent query.